# Simplest way to create a connection and execute a query on replicaset with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to execute a specific query on replica set... but without success.

What is the simplest way to create a connection and execute a query on replicaset with mongoose?

My code-1:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@host:port/db,user:pass@host2:port/db');

var someSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...}, { read: 'secondary' });
var some = mongoose.model('Some', someSchema);

some.find(...) -> err [Error: not authorized for query on bd.collection]
```

My code-2:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@host:port/db,user:pass@host2:port/db?slaveOk=true');
some.find(...) -> err [Error: not authorized for query on bd.collection]
```

My code-3:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@host:port/db,mongodb://user:pass@host2:port/db?slaveOk=true');
some.find(...) -> err [Error: not authorized for query on bd.collection]
```

My code-4:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@end:port/db,mongodb://user:pass@end2:port/db);
some.find(...) -> err [Error: not authorized for query on bd.collection]
```

My code-5:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@end:port/db,mongodb://user:pass@end2:port/db?slaveOk=true);

var someSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...});
var some = mongoose.model('Some', someSchema);

some.find(...).slaveOk() -> query executed on master (apparently)
some.find(...).read('secondary') -> query executed on master (apparently - no change on mongostat of replicaset. I'm mongoHQ user and I don't trust in mongostat from dashboard.)
```

SO, if I connect with mongo hostReplica:port/db -u user -p pass, and exec db.getMongo().setSlaveOk(), I can exec db.collection.find without problem.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to mongo client with `readPreference` option set to secondary:

```
mongodb://username:password@host:27017/database?readPreference=secondary
```

Not sure about `slaveOk` being deprecated, but `readPreference` always works.

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) and it works fine for me. My connection string for Mongoose looks like this:

```
mongodb://user:pass@host1,user:pass@host2/db?replicaSet=myReplica&readPreference=secondaryPreferred
```

I think that `slaveOk` is deprecated, and we should now use the `readPreference` option.

As I use Nodejs/Mongoose for a read-only api, I want to read from the slave(s), and keep the master for insertions mainly (which are done outside of Nodejs). That's why I use `secondaryPreferred`.